# Spring access some pages via oauth authentication, others via session authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

*I will describe my attempt for a solution here but if you have a better idea on how to seperate Authentication via OAuth and Session/Token based feel free to suggest a completly different solution.*

So I have a Spring API where a user via authorization flow first authenticates via Github, acting as identity provider. Once authenticated I am generating a session key so an API can use it for furhter requests.

My security config looks like this:

```java
        http
                .authenticationProvider(mySessionAuthProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/attribute/oauth/**").authenticated() // access only via oauth
                    .antMatchers("/attribute/session/**").authenticated() // access only via sessions
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated() // access either way
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/**").authenticated() // access only via oauth
                .and()
                    .oauth2Login() 
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(githubOauthService());
```

Logging in via OAuth works fine. But if I want to access endpoints that are authenticated via sessions only I still get the github login page. My current testing procedure is:

- Login in a browser via Oauth
- Go to an endpoint where I can get my current session key
- Enter the session key + username as Basic HTTP authentication in curl

  - `mySessionAuthProvider` takes care of verifying that (or at least it's supposed to)
- Curl replied with Githubs HTML Code of it's OAuth login mask

So TL;DR *how can I exclude certain endpoints from requiring OAuth?*